# choppy sound on youtube

Tags: sound, flash, alsa, youtube

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my Asus X75VD.
Everything works just fine except for these little sound chops I get whenever I watch a Youtube video in Firefox or in Chrome. Video and sound are perfectly in sync. It's just that every two minutes or so one or two syllables of a word disappear and you get this skipping sound (hard to describe. it sounds as if someone accidentally pushes the search button on the stereo).

I have both alsa and pulseaudio installed. However, I can't tell through which of these the sound from youtube runs through.

The soundcard is a HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH.

Any ideas or experience?

Comment: Does this happen when using other media (e.g. playing music or video)?

Comment: I don't think so. I've been running rhythmbox for the past four minutes and it didn't happen. The same goes for vlc. Of course I can't say for sure, because this chopping effect goes off at random. But it seems as if it was only reduced to flash player stuff, because it occurs on soundcloud as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using html5 player on youtube. You can set your preference on [youtube.com/html5](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

Comment: I have already done that. Is there a way you can tell you are watching a html 5 video or does anyone know a video that is definitely html 5?

Comment: Sounds like a possible work-around, so an ok "idea or experience" to answer the Q. I'd ***try*** it, never sure what will work & what won't. And when I'm using the flash player, right-clicking on the video brings up the flash menu. With HTML5, a right-click looks different (and checking `top` probably won't show any "plugin-container" process using lots of CPU)

Comment: I checked that and that's definitely not it. 
I also noticed that it's the same problem on Netflix